# Как сделать внешнюю ссылку в React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Как при нажатии на кнопку перенаправлять на внешние источники. Например на сайт https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5 . В React Native Expo

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: intent для андроид, open для виндовс

Answer (score 0):

```
const link ='https\\........'
const openLink = () => Linking.openURL(link);

<TouchableOpacity onPress={openLink}>
           <Text>link</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]